# Ivy: credentials are not sent to Nexus

Tags: ant, nexus, ivy

I am using Ivy to build my project which has several components. I want to upload these components to Nexus 2.6.4

I am able to publish files to Nexus using `curl` and the default user name and password:

```
curl -i -v -u deployment:deployment123 --upload-file a.txt http://myserver:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases/acp/myproject.app/1.0.0.20160622175545/a.txt
```

This works perfectly fine! When I go on the Nexus UI to System Feeds: Authorization and Authentication section, I can see a successful connection took place.

When I change the password to a wrong password, I can see a failed connection attempt in the Authorization and Authentication feed.

However, when I build my project using Ant I hit Unauthorized (sounds like 401). and I see absolutely nothing in the Nexus feed (this means no credentials were sent according to the Nexus documentation).

ivysettings.xml:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultBranch="${ivy.deliver.branch}" defaultResolver="default-chain" />
    <properties file="${ivy.settings.dir}/build.properties" />
    <credentials host="${repo.host}" realm="${repo.realm}"
    username="${repo.user}" passwd="${repo.pass}" />

    <resolvers>
        <filesystem name="local" transactional="true">
        <ivy
            pattern="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/local/[organisation]/[module]/[branch]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            <artifact
            pattern="${ivy.default.ivy.user.dir}/local/[organisation]/[module]/[branch]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </filesystem>
        <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-public}" />
        <ibiblio name="nexus-releases" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-releases}" />
        <chain name="default-chain">
            <resolver ref="local" />
            <resolver ref="nexus" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

build.properties contains (among other things):

```
repo.host=myserver
repo.port=8081
repo.user=deployment
repo.pass=deployment123
repo.realm=Nexus Repository Manager
bundle.publish.resolver=nexus-releases
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your realm may be incorrect. Try: "Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager".

Comment: Thank you, Mark. That was the problem indeed!

Comment: Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The realm was incorrect. The right value is `Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager`. The realm isn't necessary for using `curl` but it is when authenticating from Ant.